# Undetectable error in libCurl write function

Tags: c++, oop, curl, libcurl

In the following code I am trying to get data from a php script on a remote server in response to a post request, in a variable.

I spent so many hours finding the bug, but couldn't, this is the same code which worked perfectly in non oop environment.But now its returning all kind of wrong data, the returned data(std::string) is persistent though, for one set of post data sent the returned data(std::string) is always same.

I have checked the script with html form and there is no problem with it. So I am guessing something is wrong with my write code.

I am working in C++ and libCurl in OOP environment.

```
#include "Server.h"



namespace model
{

// private:

Server::Server (  ) 
{  

   curl_global_init ( CURL_GLOBAL_ALL );
   curl = curl_easy_init (  ) ;

};



Server* Server::singleton = NULL;


// public:

Server* Server::Instance (  )
{

    if ( !singleton ) singleton = new Server ( );

    return singleton;

};



Server::~Server ( ) 
{

   curl_easy_cleanup ( curl );
   curl_global_cleanup ( );

};



std::string Server::readScript ( std::string scriptAddress, std::string postData )
{

    std::string response = "-1";


    if ( curl ) 
    {

        curl_easy_setopt (  curl, CURLOPT_URL, scriptAddress.c_str (  )  );

        curl_easy_setopt ( curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &Server::writeString );
        curl_easy_setopt ( curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response );


        if (  ! postData.empty (  )  )
        {

            curl_easy_setopt (  curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postData.c_str (  )  );

        }


        curl_easy_setopt ( curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10L );

        CURLcode cc = curl_easy_perform ( curl );


        if (  cc == CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT  ) MessageBox ( 0, "The operation timed out.\nPlease try again later.", "Error!", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION );

        else if (  cc == CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT  )   MessageBox ( 0, "Couldn't conect to the server.\nPlease try again later.", "Error!", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION );

        else if (  cc == CURLE_REMOTE_ACCESS_DENIED  )  MessageBox ( 0, "Access is denied.\nPlease contact our support team.", "Error!", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION );

        else if (  cc == CURLE_GOT_NOTHING  )   MessageBox ( 0, "Server did not return anything.\nPlease try again later, if the problem persist please contact our support team.", "Error!", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION );

        else if (  cc == CURLE_REMOTE_FILE_NOT_FOUND  ) MessageBox ( 0, "Couldn't find resource.\nPlease try again later, if the problem persist please contact our support team.", "Error!", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION );

        else if (  cc == CURLE_FAILED_INIT  )   MessageBox ( 0, "The initialization failed.\nPlease contact our support team.", "Error!", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION );

        else if (  cc == CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST  )  MessageBox ( 0, "Couldn't resolve host.\nPlease contact our support team.", "Error!", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION );

        else if (  cc == CURLE_WRITE_ERROR  )   MessageBox ( 0, "Response write error.\nPlease contact our support team.", "Error!", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION );

        else if (  cc == CURLE_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS  )    MessageBox ( 0, "Droping connection, due to too many redirects.\nPlease contact our support team.", "Error!", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION );

        else if (  cc == CURLE_SEND_ERROR  )    MessageBox ( 0, "Failed sending data to the server.\nPlease try again later, if the problem persist please contact our support team.", "Error!", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION );

        else if (  cc == CURLE_REMOTE_FILE_NOT_FOUND  ) MessageBox ( 0, "Remote server could not be found.\nPlease try again later, if the problem persist please contact our support team.", "Error!", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION );

        MessageBox( 0, response.c_str(), "response", 0 );

    }

    else
    {

        MessageBox ( 0, "Something went wrong.\nPlease try again later.", "Error!", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION );

    }


    return response;

};





/**     private static function     */
/** -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/** -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */


int Server::writeString ( void *ptr, int size, int count, void *stream ) 
{


  ( ( std::string* ) stream )->append (  ( char* ) ptr, 0, size*count  );


  return size*count;


}


};// end of namespace model
```

**EDIT:**
When I am expecting **0** it returns **-10**, when **3** is expected it returns **-13**, when **1** is expected it returns **-11** and so on.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your append position was wrong.

replace your write function

```
((std::string*)stream)->append((char*)ptr,0,size*count);
```

to follow code.

```
((std::string* )stream)->append((char*)ptr);
```

Comment: didn't work, same result. I have added some more information to the original post.

Comment: your write function was called more than one times,so your append position is wrong.

maybe you can use "[wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html)" to check your post data.
some webserver can detect your post is not from browser so return the wrong data.

Comment: maybe cookies is necessary.

Comment: We were missing a very basic problem :), Thanks a lot for the time, discussing with you and your comment "so your append position is wrong" made me think :)

Answer (score 0):

Am such a fool, I am initialing std::string response = "-1"; so every "append" in the Server::writeString appends the result at the end of "-1". Need to make sure that if there is a response from the server first clear the std::string.